# Green Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently fiddled with the "advance" color settings and changed the 3d objects color to green to go with a green theme. While SSMS adapts nicely to the change, VS 2008 does not.

Is there a way to make VS follow the SSMS way of blending in ?

Screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot]

Specs:
Windows 7 RC1
Visual Studio 2008 SP1
SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (engine - SP1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so if it doesn't just automatically do it.

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 has the ability to import and export all its settings, including visual styles.  I haven't worked with SSMS, but if it has a *Tools/Import and Export Settings...* menu they might be interoperable.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because SSMS 2008 is based on the VS 2005 shell.